# Django Test, 'SQLCompiler' object has no attribute 'col_count'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

**What I'm Testing**

I'm attempting to unit test the `annotate_active` queryset inside my  `models.py`,

```
class ServerQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def annotate_active(self, start=None, end=None):
        return self.annotate(
            active=Case(
                When(fqdn__in=self.get_active_fqdns(), then=True),
                default=False,
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )


class Server(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = ServerQuerySet.as_manager()
```

**How it Works**

`get_active_fqdns` just returns a set of fqdn values `{'va1', 'val2', ...}`

When I execute the query in the django shell everything works fine:

```
~/Documents/piesup2 master* ⇡ 1m 15s
venv ❯ python manage.py shell --settings=piesup2.settings.test

>>> from reports.models import Server
>>> Server.objects.annotate_active().values_list('fqdn', 'active')
<QuerySet [('101.104.243.11', False), ('101.203.185.232', False), ('103.110.68.247', False), ('103.201.105.197', False), ('103.47.83.167', False), ('1.119.79.204', False), ('1.152.209.127', False), ('120.14.125.221', False), ('120.14.95.12', False), ('127.239.228.52', False), ('127.94.245.121', False), ('133.107.3.133', False), ('143.65.89.141', False), ('151.161.235.135', False), ('162.54.208.170', False), ('170.252.228.176', False), ('170.55.42.194', False), ('171.210.89.116', False), ('175.166.243.88', False), ('175.62.108.95', False), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

**Failing Test**

I have the following test case inside `test_server.py` (I expect this test to fail at the assertion)

```
from django.test import TestCase
from reports.models import Server


class TestServerQuerySet(TestCase):

    def test_annotate_active(self):
        result = Server.objects.annotate_active().values_list('fqdn', 'active')
        print(result)
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

However when I run the test with:

```
python manage.py test reports.tests.test_server --settings=piesup2.settings.test
```

I get an AttributeError when it executes the query:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_annotate_active (reports.tests.test_server.TestServerQuerySet)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/reports/tests/test_server.py", line 9, in test_annotate_active
    print(result)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 790, in results_iter
    fields = [s[0] for s in self.select[0:self.col_count]]
AttributeError: 'SQLCompiler' object has no attribute 'col_count'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.010s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Worth Noting:**

- Rest of the test suite runs fine (~140 tests with DB read/writes)
- Example shell output is using the same `settings/test.py` file as my test-suite.

There seems to be some sort of conflict in my environment whereby my test breaks when running an django's conditional `Case` query.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it is late :) but if some one has same problem

This is a Django bug that was fixed in 1.9.1.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25894